# prevent click on mouseup

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

how to prevent anchor tag click on hold and drag ? like when i hold the mouse and drag left and right its ok, but if i moved my hand from the mouse the a click will happen , i tried to use prevent default on mouse up but it didn't work

```
<a>
 <img src=""/>
</a>
```

and here is my javascript

```
const projectList = document.querySelector('.projects-list');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

projectList.addEventListener('mousedown', (e)=>{
    isDown = true;
    projectList.classList.add('active');
    startX = e.pageX - projectList.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = projectList.scrollLeft;
    projectList.classList.add('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});

projectList.addEventListener('mouseleave', ()=>{
    isDown = false;
    projectList.classList.remove('active');
});

projectList.addEventListener('mouseup', ()=>{
    isDown = false;
    projectList.classList.remove('active');
});

projectList.addEventListener('mousemove', (e)=>{
    if ( !isDown ) return; // stop the function from running
    e.preventDefault();
    const x = e.pageX - projectList.offsetLeft;
    const walk = x - startX;
    projectList.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put attribute `class="projects-list"` in anchor tag
Given sample of html doesnt have element with `.projects-list` anywhere

Also `querySelector` only find the first matching element
Alternative: `querySelectorAll`

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, the question is how to stop the click from happening, but good point

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault` on the `<a>`, like this:

```js
var canClick = false;

$("#NoClick").click(function() {
    if (!canClick) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

$("#Click").click(function() {
    if (canClick) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

$("button").click(function() {
    canClick = !canClick;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Swap</button>
<br>
<a href="www.google.com" id="Click">This will work</a>
<br>
<a href="www.google.com" id="NoClick">This won't work</a>
```

Except you can change the canClick in the `mousedown` and `mouseup` functions to avoid your problem